# Angular2 equivalent to template inheritance

Tags: angular

In my angular2 app I have the AppModule, the AppComponent (only consists of router-outlet) and a LoginComponent:

```
<form><input type="password"></form>
```

... and a list with documents (DocumentsComponent):

```
<nav>...</nav>
<ul>
 <li>Document A</li>
 <li>Document B</li>
 <li>Document C</li>
</ul>
```

... and a list with users (UsersComponent):

```
<nav>...</nav>
<ul>
 <li>User A</li>
 <li>User B</li>
 <li>User C</li>
</ul>
```

The login should be in fullscreen. So there is no navigation. On all other components there should be a navigation. So in the real app it's not only the navigation. There are a lot more components around the content.

In Twig I would use something like extend. But I know that the structure and idea of templating in Angular is different.

So where should I put the "wrapper" (navigation, footer, ...) and show it in the Documents- and UsersComponent but not in LoginComponent, RegisterComponent, ErrorComponent,....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [child routes](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#child-routing-component)

or if your user is not logged in, just put login form in front of app with position fixed to hide everything from user - this is easy but kind of dirty solution

you can also use [hierarchical di](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html) to place some component where you want

or [Compile](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Compiler-class.html#!#compileModuleAsync-anchor) your component in dynamic way but this is the worst scenario here